# Woocommerce show product published date on shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for solution to display products published date on shop page.

I would very greatful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show Product Published Date Shop and Single Page in WooCommerce

add the below function in function.php file

```
  //WooCommerce Shop Page : Show Product Published Date
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_shop_page_product_date', 100 );
    function wc_shop_page_product_date() {
        echo the_date('', '<span class="date_published">Published on: ', '</span>', false);
    }

    //WooCommerce Single Page : Show Product Published Date
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','wc_single_page_product_date',25);
    function wc_single_page_product_date() {
        if (is_product() ) {
            echo the_date('', '<span class="date_published">Published on: ', '</span>', false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't need solution for single page because I've already figure it out. But still thanks. Anyway. Your solution only gave me a published date for first 2 products :(

Comment: My mistake. I think everythink is alright. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','show_product_date',28);
function show_product_date() {
  if (is_product() ) {
    echo the_date('', '<p class="product_date">Published on: ', '</p>', false);
  } 
}
```