# Woocommerce show published date on shop page and not the modified one

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce

thank you for your attention.
Hoping someone will be able to kindly give me some feedback on how to correct the code necessary for my site. Before starting, I would like to state that I'm not in any way a php expert. I can do my best to follow easy instructions, but anything harder, may be not possible.

After installing and tweaking Woocommerce on my Wordpress site, I discovered that both the shop page and the single product page wouldn't show the published date.

So, I tried to search online for some way to fix it and found the following thread: [Woocommerce show product published date on shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627695/woocommerce-show-product-published-date-on-shop-page)
I tried to use the reported code and it worked almost perfectly; the date get nicely showed in the product page, whilst I met a little problem on the shop page: it would show correctly the date of only the first product of the actual page(so, only 1 of 9 products would show the date; the same thing would happen if I moved to the next page).

Searching for some ways to fix that problem, I did find another similar code, which would display the date of the last modification([Display the modified date of every product on Woocommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450128/display-the-modified-date-of-every-product-on-woocommerce-shop-page)); I tried to integrate part of that code and it finaly showed the date for each product, on the shop page.
But, there is still a problem: it show the last modification date and not the published one, which cause it to show some wrong dates(for example, the products are set in order of when they got published, but then you can see an old product with a more recent date in the middle of other old products with the right date).

The actual code I'm using now is the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_shop_page_product_date', 100 );
function wc_shop_page_product_date()
{
    global $product;

    echo '<br><span class="date_published">Uscito il: ' . $product->get_date_modified()->date('d/m/Y') . '</span>';
}
```

I attempted multiple times to change the "modified date" to the "published date", which resulted in the site crashing and forcing me to restore everything to default settings(without plugins and default theme, and spending a few minutes reactivating everything), so, after the umpteenth failed attempt, I gave up, deciding that it would be best to try to find some help from someone a bit more expert, before risking to completely corrupt the site.

Comment: How about using get_the_date('Y-m-d', $product->get_id()) instead of $product->get_date_modified()->date('d/m/Y') ?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: Thank you! That solved it perfectly and with not crash ;) Thank you very much for your kind answer which helped me to solve the problem that was really driving me crazy.